# What are the differences between LDAP and SQL?

Tags: sql, ldap

I have read that LDAP is used to store information about users and many other objects. Since this can be done with any databases like SQL, why LDAP is used for this purpose?

Comment: Check the answer on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075394/difference-between-sql-and-ldap (superuser sister site)

Comment: Beware of the differences between "Can be done" and "Can be done without it being a major pain in the ass".

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is a protocol referenced [RFC 4511 LDAP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511)

An the protocol is the layer 7 of the OSI network, associated to an application with socket. You're right the boot could provide the same information but they're not delivered in the same form. That's the point.